# getting black screen while trying to record dockerized lxde using ffmpeg

Tags: video, vnc, ffmpeg, opengl, lxde

I have created a docker image that has LXDE and TightVNCServer.

```
# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu

# Install LXDE and VNC server.
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y lxde-core lxterminal tightvncserver
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN touch /root/.Xresources
RUN touch /root/.Xauthority
COPY xstartup /root/.vnc/xstartup
RUN chmod +x /root/.vnc/xstartup
#Install Node.js & npm

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

COPY * /data

RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

I am running this container using this command:

`docker run -it --rm -v /data:/data -p 5901:5901 -e USER=root ubuntudsktp  bash -c "vncserver :1 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 24 && tail -F /root/.vnc/*.log"`

I am logging into this container using VNC and running this command to record the whole screen:

`ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :1.0 output.webm`

After the recording was over, I opened the video and I could see that the video is completely blank(black screen).

this is also my input when i try to run `glxinfo`:

```
# glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
Error: unable to open display
```

I have also tried to run it using:

`DISPLAY=:1 ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :1.0 output.webm`
And the results are the same.

What I am missing here?

Comment: If you are on Wayland, maybe try to use Xorg?